# "Sie ist die beste Lehrerin". Womit vergleicht man? Nur mit weiblichen Dozenten?

Tags: gender

Was versteht man unter folgendem Satz?

> Heutzutage ist [Nathalie Stutzmann](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nathalie_Stutzmann) die beste Orchesterdirigentin!

*Kontext: Gleich nach ihrem Konzert hört man einem Mann zu, diesen Satz munter auszusprechen.*

Drückt der Typ aus, dass er bloß Nathalie Stutzmann – unter allen Orchesterdirigentinnen – für die allerbeste hält? Oder, dass er Frau Stutzmann für den besten Dirigenten (Mann oder Frau) hält? Hat der Satz eine (eventuelle) sexistische Konnotation?

Comment: Es gab in den Kommentaren [zu dieser Antwort von mir](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/17173/2594) schon einige Diskussionen darüber.

Comment: In the context you mention (*munter* == *belustigt*?), it seems to be a joke that uses discrimination in a technical sense.

Answer (score 4):

Der Satz

> Heutzutage ist Nathalie Stutzmann die beste Orchesterdirigentin!

ist insofern doppeldeutig, dass man ohne weiteren Zusammenhang nicht sagen kann, ob der Sprecher nur weibliche oder alle Orchesterdirigenten meinte. Um den Satz eindeutig zu gestalten, kann man z. B. Folgendes sagen:

> Heutzutage ist Nathalie Stutzmann die beste aller Orchesterdirigenten!

Eine sexistische Konnotation sehe ich darin allerdings nicht.