# Wie kann man "Er ist der erfolgreichste Teilnehmer des Wettbewerbs" klarer machen?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> Er ist der erfolgreichste Teilnehmer des Wettbewerbs.

Ist er nur mit männlichen Teilnehmern verglichen, oder mit sowohl männlichen als auch weiblichen Teilnehmern? In [dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18404/sie-ist-die-beste-lehrerin-womit-vergleicht-man-nur-mit-weiblichen-dozenten) wird behauptet, dass es unklar ist.

Wie kann man den Satz klarer machen, wenn man die eine oder die andere Bedeutung im Sinn hat? Das Folgende wird leider auch nicht helfen:

> Er ist der erfolgreichste **aller** Teilnehmer des Wettbewerbs.

Comment: “(dieser Satz verwendet das generische Maskulinum)”

Comment: Wie wäre es denn mit "er ist Sieger"? (Oder Gewinner?)

Comment: Was ist denn daran unklar??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ich widerspreche der Behauptung, der Satz

> Er ist der erfolgreichste Teilnehmer des Wettbewerbs.

wäre unklar. Es sind ganz klar ALLE Teilnehmer gemeint, egal ob es sich dabei um Männer, Frauen, Kinder, Roboter, Hunde usw. handelt. Über die Beschaffenheit der übrigen Teilnehmer wird keinerlei Aussage gemacht, daher wird diese Menge auch in keiner Weise eingeschränkt.

Nehmen wir an, bei dem Wettbewerb geht es darum, von einem Zwei-Meter-Podest herunter, und unmittelbar nach der Landung wieder möglichst hoch zu springen. Sieger ist, wer beim Wieder-hoch-springen am höchsten kommt.

Es nehmen teil: zwei erwachsene Männer, vier erwachsene Frauen, drei Kinder, zwei Fußbälle, ein Tischtennisball, eine Teetasse und ein Buch. Von allen Teilnehmern springt der Tischtennisball nach dem Fall vom Podest am höchsten. Über ihn sagt man dann:

> Er ist der erfolgreichste Teilnehmer des Wettbewerbs.

Und dabei wird er keineswegs nur mit anderen Tischtennisbällen verglichen, sondern eben mit *ALLEN* Teilnehmern.

Comment: +1 Sehe ich auch so. In der verlinkten Frage ist von einer Frau die Rede, und analog könnte man hier streiten, ob "die erfolgreichste Teilnehmerin" mit allen vergleicht oder nur mit den Frauen. Bei Männern sind es klar alle, und wer nur mit den Männern vergleichen will, muss explizit einschränken.

Comment: @Matthias: Das Problem ist nun mal leider, dass eine kleine, aber laute Teilgruppe der Sprecherschaft des Deutschen die Position vertritt, dass *Teilnehmer* auf männliche solche eingeschränkt sei. Ich habe die Frage so verstanden, dass es darum geht, Unklarheiten zu vermeiden, die durch eine mögliche Interpretation des Wortes auf diese Weise (sei es durch den Schreiber oder den Leser) entstehen können.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Diese Teilgruppe der Sprecherschaft ist eine kleine Minderheit, die zwar hehre Ziele verfolgt, in diesem Punkt aber dennoch irrt. Wenn das nächste Mal jemand meint, mit »Nudeln« wäre alles mögliche, nur nicht Farfalle gemeint, wird man deswegen die Überschriften auf Speisekarten auch nicht ändern müssen. Wenn die Angehören dieser Teilgruppe es partout falsch verstehen wollen, dass sollen sie eben. Das ist dann aber ohnehin deren Problem. Alle anderen verstehen es genau so wie es gemeint ist.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ich bin alles andere als ein Freund dieser Ansicht, aber die Grundprämisse der Frage (zumindest so wie ich sie verstehe) ist eben, dass deren Interpretation berücksichtigt werden soll.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Die verlinkte Frage alleine gibt diese Grundprämisse m.E. nicht her, aber Du könntest natürlich trotzdem Recht haben. Vielleicht äußert sich boaten ja noch dazu.

Comment: Wenn viele hier sich dahin einigen, dass die Mehrheit der Sprecherschaft das Wort *Teilnehmer* im Satz als *alle* Teilnehmer interpretiert, dann bin ich schon zufrieden. Es ist aber auch interessant zu wissen, dass es die Minderheit gibt.

Comment: Es ist aber schon auffällig, dass Du nur angibst, wie der Satz lautet, wenn der Ball gewinnt, nicht aber, wenn eine Frau oder Tasse gewinnt.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: 1. Weder eine Frau noch eine Tasse springen nach einem Fall aus 2 Meter höher als ein Tischtennisball. 2. Es ging in der Frage ausdrücklich um (grammatisch) männliche Teilnehmer, denn bei weiblichen treten eben genau die hinlänglich bekannten Unklarheiten auf. Im Satz »Sie ist die erfolgreichste Teilnehmerin des Wettbewerbs.« ist zunächst unklar, ob sie unter allen oder nur unter den weiblichen Teilnehmern die erfolgreichste war. Diese Unklarheit gibt es nicht bei männlichen Teilnehmern, außer man konstruiert sie mutwillig.

Comment: Wenn Du nicht "sie ist der erfolgreichste Teilnehmer" schreiben würdest, ist die männliche Form vielleicht doch nicht so neutral wie Du behauptest. Aber natürlich bekommt man hier Applaus dafür, Unklarheiten unter den Tisch zu kehren.

Answer (score 3):

Die einfachsten Fassungen, die selbst hartnäckige Sprachfalschversteher nicht fehlinterpretieren können und die mir einfallen, sind:

- Wenn mit Teilnehmern beiderlei Geschlechts verglichen wird:

  > Von allen Teilnehmerinnen und Teilnehmern des Wettbewerbs war er der erfolgreichste.
- Wenn nur mit männlichen Teilnehmern verglichen wird:

  > Er war der erfolgreichste männliche Teilnehmer des Wettbewerbs.

Comment: Bin skeptisch. "Von allen Teilnehmerinnen war er der erfolgreichste." Das funktioniert grammatisch nicht. Die Teilnehmerinnen sind daher nicht wirklich  in den Satz integriert.

Comment: @Emanuel: "Von allen Teilnehmerinnen und Teilnehmern war er die oder der erfolgreichste."?

Comment: @Emanuel: Das Problem sehe ich nicht. Ich habe auch kein Problem damit zu schreiben »Sie war der erfolgreichste Teilnehmer des Wettbewerbs« oder halt »Von allen Teilnehmern war sie die erfolgreichste.«

Comment: Ich sehe Emanuels Problem nicht, biete aber trotzdem „am erfolgreichsten“ an.

Answer (score 2):

Ich denke, wenn man sicherstellen will, daß wirklich niemand meckert, könnte man sagen:

> Bei diesem Wettbewerb war (er/sie/es) *am
>   erfolgreichsten*.

[EDIT, danke Hubert: ich hatte zunächst etwas anderes geschrieben]
Auf diese Weise wird an keiner Stelle irgend ein Geschlecht von irgend einem beteiligten außer der aktuell interessanten Person erwähnt.

[Edit2]
Ich stimme ansonsten Hubert Schönalst zu: Den Original-Satz falsch zu verstehen erfordert schon ein gewisses Maß an Vorsatz.

Comment: Danke, @HubertSchölnast: ich habe meine Antwort korrigiert.

Comment: "**an** diesem Wettbewerb" habe ich evtl. mal in der Schweiz gehört. In Deutschland sagt man, glaube ich, immer "**in**".

Comment: @Matthias: Ja, in der Schweiz ist das standardsprachlich: _an der Konferenz_, _an der Weltmeisterschaft_, _an einem Vortrag_ usw. Es entspricht im Deutschlanddeutschen meistens _bei_.

Comment: @chirlu Ja, "bei" klingt besser. Ich habe wohl zulange in der Schweiz gelebt. Danbke für den hinweis, ich habs korrigiert

Comment: Wobei wir keine deutschländische Veranstaltung sind, Schweizer Einschlag ist durchaus in Ordnung.

Comment: @chirlu beim ersten Teil stimme ich zu, der zweite Teil ist Geschmackssache ;-)

Answer (score 0):

- Er ist der erfolgreichste Teilnehmer in allen Kategorien. Er ist auch
  erfolgreicher als die Frauen.
- Sie ist die erfolgreichste Teinehmerin in allen Kategorien. Sie ist
  auch erfolgreicher als alle Männer/männlichen Läufer.

"*Er war der erfolgreichste männliche Teilnehmer des Wettbewerbs.*" ist aus meiner Sicht nicht korrekt. Die informatorische Einschränkung bezieht sich nicht auf sein Geschlecht, sondern das Geschlecht der anderen Sportler. Also:

- Er ist der erfolgreichste Teilnehmer unter den männlichen Läufern.
- Sie ist die erfolgreichste Teilnehmerin unter den weiblichen Sportlern.

Comment: Nun ja, da er nunmal schon männlich ist muss mit *Er war der erfolgreichste männliche Teilnehmer des Wettbewerbs.* sein eigenes Geschlecht auch nicht mehr eingeschränkt werden. Das gleiche geschieht ja auch bei den beiden Optionen. Es wird jeweils das Geschlecht derer eingeschränkt mit denen er/sie verglichen wird. Es wird jedoch keine Aussage über das gesamte Teilnehmerfeld gemacht.